# c# Generic methods: Type argument required

Tags: c#, generics, types, arguments, required

Getting error:

**Using generic method 'Program.Sort3Vars(T[],T[],T[])' requires 1 type arguments.**

Aren't they defined here?

```
Sort3Vars<int, string, string>(cost, var1, var2);
```

This is for a sort algorithm I am making. I want to be able to sort by an integer or a string or a double etc. without having to write the same method multiple times with just a different datatype.

This is my code where I am getting the error.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] cost = { 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1 };
        public static double[] costdouble = { 2.5, 4.30, 3.33, 4, 2, 1.10 };
        public static string[] var1 = { "apple", "mango", "banana", "grapes", "chicken", "ham" };
        public static string[] var2 = { "fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "meat", "meat", };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sort3Vars<int, string, string>(cost, var1, var2);
            //Using generic method 'Program.Sort3Vars(T[],T[],T[])' requires 1 type arguments.
        }

        public static void Sort3Vars<T>(T[] tkey, T[] tvar1, T[] tvar2)
        {
            //sort tvar1, tvar2 by cost/tkey stub.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method has **one** generic type and you want to have **three** ...

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks. I am fairly new to c# so wasn't fully understanding generics. I added T, U and X and that seemed to do the trick! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a method with 3 arguments and one generic parameter, `T`, that is the same for all 3 arguments. You want a method with 3 generic parameters, one for each argument:

```
public static void Sort3Vars<TKey, T1, T2>(TKey[] tkey, T1[] tvar1, T2[] tvar2)
{
    //sort tvar1, tvar2 by cost/tkey stub.
}
```